# In the code below, I get an error as "first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects". How can I fix this?

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I'm trying to understand how iteration in Python works. Isn't the first method the same as the second method? How can we write the first method with the traditional method?

I get an error in second way:
TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
path = r'C:\Documents'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt")) 

df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files) #1. way

# 2. way
# for f in all_files:
#     df_from_each_file=(pd.read_csv(f))


concatenated_df   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
print(concatenated_df)
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: you have to create empty list before `for`-loop and inside loop use `.append()` to add element to this list.

Comment: third way: `df_from_each_file = list(map(pd.read_csv, all_files))` (eventually you can skip `list()`)

Comment: @furas Right,  `pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, all_files))` looks like very good option. 

Comment: ```pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, all_files))``` in this case how can we use ```pd.read_csv``` arguments like sep, encoding, header etc.

Comment: use `partial`, detail in the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73295694/14909621)

Answer (score 2):

In the second case the line `df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f))` just assigns a dataframe obtained from the latest file to your variable. You pass as an argument a single object (data from the last file), so `pd.concat` has nothing to concatenate. That's why it says `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects`

To make it work use some iterable container, e.g. `list`:

```
df_from_each_file = []
for f in all_files:
    df_from_each_file.append(pd.read_csv(f))
```

---

P.S. *How can we use `pd.read_csv` arguments like `sep`, `encoding`, `header` etc. with `pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, all_files))`?*

For this purpose we use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?functools.partial#functools.partial):

```
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial
from io import StringIO

data1 = '''name;value
one;1
two;2
'''

data2 = '''name;value
three;3
four;4
'''

csv_files = [
    StringIO(data1),
    StringIO(data2)
]

my_read_csv = partial(pd.read_csv, sep=";")

df = pd.concat(map(my_read_csv, csv_files))
display(df)
```

[image: code with explanation]